# Can "Dylib Hijacking" really happen on iOS app?

Tags: ios, security

I have a question about **Dylib Hijacking**.
I'm told that this vulnerability exists on Mac application.
Ref. https://www.virusbulletin.com/virusbulletin/2015/03/dylib-hijacking-os-x

And he told me that it can also happen on iOS app.
I googled a lot for searching the solution or even any discussion about it, but nothing was found about iOS app.

So, now I'm wondering if it really can happen on iOS app. After some investigation, my understanding is that to this vulnerability happens, the following conditions must be satisfied:

- The malicious library has to be found before the app can find the correct library
- Attackers have to have write permission to the folder
- Attackers have to launch the app after injecting the malicious library

In my iOS app case, all of the libraries are found in the 2nd ranked RPATH `@executable_path/Frameworks`, so attackers have to place the malicious library in the 1st ranked RPATH `/usr/lib/swift`. Here are the questions:

- Is the folder `/usr/lib/swift` writable in iOS devices in general?
- If it requires Jailbroken, can’t we avoid this issue by forbidding those devices from using our app?

If you're aware of this vulnerability on iOS app, that is totally helpful.
But even if you are not, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should maybe be asked on a more security-focused SE site, e.g. https://security.stackexchange.com/ !?

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks. That makes sense. I posted there. https://security.stackexchange.com/q/258922/272995